# Google collections presentation slides on the web?

Tags: java, guava

Are the slides of the presentation linked from the [Google collections page](http://code.google.com/p/google-collections/) available somewhere as pdf or so on the web ? I.e. I'm looking for the slides of the [overview video](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ZeO_J2OcHYM) as it is easier to search e.g. a pdf than a video...

I know that Google collections is now part of [Guava Libraries](http://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/) but the 'PDF Slides of a recent presentation' are quite brief on the collections part.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Do you mean [those slides](http://code.google.com/p/google-collections/downloads/detail?name=google-collections-svgtug-2008-08-06.pdf&can=2&q=) ?

Comment: Beware this slides are quite old now.

Answer (score 4):

There are several presentations available online:

- [Effective Java: Still Effective, After All These Years](http://google-collections.googlecode.com/files/collections-connection.pdf) (from JavaOne 2009)
- [Guava: a sketchy overview](http://guava-libraries.googlecode.com/files/Guava_a_sketchy_overview.pdf) (2009-09-15)
- [The Google Collections Library](http://google-collections.googlecode.com/.../google-collections-svgtug-2008-08-06.pdf) (2008-08-06)

Answer (score 3):

A more up-to-date version can be found here on the Guava project:
http://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/downloads/list